# Why aren't Enumerations Iterable?

Tags: java, enumeration, iterable

In Java 5 and above you have the foreach loop, which works magically on anything that implements `Iterable`:

```
for (Object o : list) {
  doStuff(o);
}
```

However, `Enumerable` still does not implement `Iterable`, meaning that to iterate over an `Enumeration` you must do the following:

```
for(; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
  doStuff(e.nextElement());
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a reason why `Enumeration` still does not implement `Iterable`?

**Edit:** As a clarification, I'm not talking about the language concept of an [enum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type), I'm talking a Java-specific class in the Java API called '[Enumeration](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)'.

Comment: Shouldn't that be  doStuff(e.nextElement()) inside the block?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Enumeration hasn't been modified to support Iterable because it's an interface not a concrete class (like Vector, which was modifed to support the Collections interface).

If Enumeration was changed to support Iterable it would break a bunch of people's code.

Comment: Still, given that there is for-each support for **both** Iterable **and** arrays, why didn't sun include Enumerable as well?

Comment: @Adrian Kuhn: they didn't include for-each support for Iterator, and Enumerable behaves like an Iterator, not an Iterable.

Comment: Enumeration is not IteraBLE. Enumeratrion is actually IteraTOR (but without 'delete') http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197868/117220. With this clarification the answer is that this would break existing APIs. It would be possible to do this backwards-compatibly if partial implementation is allowed in Interfaces (like in Scala traits).

Comment: @PetrGladkikh: Yet they still didn't fix it in Java 8.

Comment: @JohnEye Even with default methods in Java 8, it's not possible to fully implement an `Enumeration`-based `Iterable`. There's nothing to "fix"; `Enumeration` and `Iterable` are not logically equivalent types, and a conversion utility to correctly bridge the gap between them is already provided in `Collections.list()`

Comment: it is even stranger since java9. There is method
`default Iterator<E> asIterator()` in `interface Enumeration<E>`
I hope there was good reason not to name the method simply `default Iterator<E> iterator()` what would allow make `interface Enumeration<E> extend Iterable<E>`

Answer (score 82):

As an easy and **clean** way of using an Enumeration with the enhanced for loop, convert to an ArrayList with java.util.Collections.list.

```
for (TableColumn col : Collections.list(columnModel.getColumns()) {
```

(javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel.getColumns returns Enumeration.)

Note, this may be very slightly less efficient.

Comment: Funny: this (columns in the column model) is the exact reason I found this question.

Answer (score 51):

It doesn't make sense for `Enumeration` to implement `Iterable`. `Iterable` is a factory method for `Iterator`. `Enumeration` is analogous to `Iterator`, and only maintains state for a single enumeration.

So, be careful trying to wrap an `Enumeration` as an `Iterable`. If someone passes me an `Iterable`, I will assume that I can call `iterator()` on it repeatedly, creating as many `Iterator` instances as I want, and iterating independently on each. A wrapped `Enumeration` will not fulfill this contract; don't let your wrapped `Enumeration` escape from your own code. (As an aside, I noticed that Java 7's [`DirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) violates expectations in just this way, and shouldn't be allowed to "escape" either.)

`Enumeration` is like an `Iterator`, not an `Iterable`. A `Collection` is `Iterable`. An `Iterator` is not.

You can't do this:

```
Vector<X> list = …
Iterator<X> i = list.iterator();
for (X x : i) {
    x.doStuff();
}
```

So it wouldn't make sense to do this:

```
Vector<X> list = …
Enumeration<X> i = list.enumeration();
for (X x : i) {
    x.doStuff();
}
```

There is no `Enumerable` equivalent to `Iterable`. It could be added without breaking anything to work in for loops, but what would be the point? If you are able to implement this new `Enumerable` interface, why not just implement `Iterable` instead?

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK Enumeration is [kinda "deprecated"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

> Iterator takes the place of
>   Enumeration in the Java collections
>   framework

I hope they'll change the Servlet API with JSR 315 to use Iterator instead of Enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

If you would just like it to be syntactically a little cleaner, you can use:

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
  doStuff(e.nextElement());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an Iterable from any object with a method that returns an Enumeration, using a lambda as an adapter. In Java 8, use Guava's static [`Iterators.forEnumeration`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#forEnumeration(java.util.Enumeration)) method, and in Java 9+ use the Enumeration instance method [`asIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html#asIterator--).

Consider the Servlet API's `HttpSession.getAttributeNames()`, which returns an `Enumeration<String>` rather than an `Iterator<String>`.

**Java 8 using Guava**

```java
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> Iterators.forEnumeration(session.getAttributeNames());
```

**Java 9+**

```java
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> session.getAttributeNames().asIterator();
```

Note that these lambdas are truly Iterable; they return a fresh Iterator each time they are invoked. You can use them exactly like any other Iterable in an enhanced `for` loop, `StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)`, and `iterable.forEach()`.

The same trick works on classes that provide an Iterator but don't implement Iterable. `Iterable<Something> iterable = notIterable::createIterator;`