# Why can't I use foreach on Java Enumeration?

Tags: java, loops

Why can't I do:

```
Enumeration e = ...
for (Object o : e)
  ...
```

Comment: Enumeration was replaced by Iterator in Java 1.2 in 1998 and is retained for legacy support.  The real question is why you want to use it.  Possibly because you use a library which forces you to do so?

Comment: @Peter - yes, an external library is the answer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Because [`Enumeration<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) doesn't extend [`Iterable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Here is an [example of making Iterable Enumerations](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html) using the adapter pattern.

As to why that's an interesting question. This isn't exactly your question but it sheds some light on it. From the [Java Collections API Design FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html):

> **Why doesn't Iterator extend Enumeration?**
>
> We view the method names for
> Enumeration as unfortunate. They're
> very long, and very frequently used.
> Given that we were adding a method and
> creating a whole new framework, we
> felt that it would be foolish not to
> take advantage of the opportunity to
> improve the names. Of course we could
> support the new and old names in
> Iterator, but it doesn't seem
> worthwhile.

That basically suggests to me that Sun wants to distance themselves from Enumeration, which is very early Java with quite a verbose syntax.

Comment: Next question: why aren't Enumerations Iterable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240/why-arent-enumerations-iterable

Comment: Is there a semantic difference between the two? (I'm not familiar with the Iterable class)? Why not have for work on Enumeration as well?

Comment: Because Enumerations are more akin to Iterator, not Iterable (see the stackoverflow question mmyers posted). As a workaround, you can do `for(; e.hasMoreElements(); ) { e.getNextElement(); }`

Comment: But `Iterators` are not `Iterable` either. You can't do `for (obj : itr)`. The reason for this is that `Iterable` is really *repeatedly iterable*, whereas an iterator can only be iterated over once.

Comment: Do you mean "Enumeration<T> doesnt Implement Iterably<T>" instead of extends?

Comment: This doesn't explain why Sun/Oracle didn't allow an `Enumeration` in the new `for` syntax as well as an `Iterable` and an `array`.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674/822870) is a one line "fix" to use an Enumeration in an enhanced for loop ("foreach")

Answer (score 50):

Using the `Collections` utility class, `Enumeration` can be made iterable like:

```java
Enumeration headerValues=request.getHeaders("mycustomheader");
List headerValuesList=Collections.list(headerValues);

for(Object headerValueObj:headerValuesList){
 ... do whatever you want to do with headerValueObj
}
```

This uses the [`Collections.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#list(java.util.Enumeration)) method, which copies the `Enumeration` data into a new `ArrayList`.

> Returns an array list containing the elements returned by the specified enumeration in the order they are returned by the enumeration. This method provides interoperability between legacy APIs that return enumerations and new APIs that require collections.

Comment: The elements are copied in a new list before starting the iteration, this solution should be avoided for long enumerations. The solutions turning an Enumeration into an Iterator have less memory overhead.

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg but they have side effects, as enumerations are stateful.

Comment: This is by far the easiest answer! No dependencies needed, and clearly readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this problem with two very simple classes, one for `Enumeration` and one for `Iterator`.  The enumeration wrapper is as follows:

```
static class IterableEnumeration<T>
extends Object
implements Iterable<T>, Iterator<T>
{
private final Enumeration<T>        enumeration;
private boolean                     used=false;

IterableEnumeration(final Enumeration<T> enm) {
    enumeration=enm;
    }

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    if(used) { throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot use iterator from asIterable wrapper more than once"); }
    used=true;
    return this;
    }

public boolean hasNext() { return enumeration.hasMoreElements(); }
public T       next()    { return enumeration.nextElement();     }
public void    remove()  { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove elements from AsIterator wrapper around Enumeration"); }
}
```

Which can be used either with a static utility method (which is my preference):

```
/**
 * Convert an `Enumeration<T>` to an `Iterable<T>` for a once-off use in an enhanced for loop.
 */
static public <T> Iterable<T> asIterable(final Enumeration<T> enm) {
    return new IterableEnumeration<T>(enm);
    }

...

for(String val: Util.asIterable(enm)) {
    ...
    }
```

or by instantiating the class:

```
for(String val: new IterableEnumeration<String>(enm)) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The new-style-for-loop ("foreach") works on arrays, and things that implement the `Iterable` interface.

It's also more analogous to `Iterator` than to `Iterable`, so it wouldn't make sense for `Enumeration` to work with foreach unless `Iterator` did too (and it doesn't). 
`Enumeration` is also discouraged in favor of `Iterator`.

Comment: Let's be careful with terms here. Deprecation means something very specific when discussing APIs. Use of Enumeration is discouraged, but it's _not_ deprecated.

Comment: ykaganovich: good point. I've corrected the text in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With java 8 and beyond this is possible:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;

Enumeration e = ...;
Collections.list(e).forEach(o -> {
    ... // use item "o"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enumeration` doesn't implement `Iterable` and as such can't be used directly in a foreach loop. However using [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections) it's possible to iterate over an enumeration with:

```
for (Object o : new IteratorIterable(new EnumerationIterator(e))) {
    ...
}
```

You could also use a shorter syntax with `Collections.list()` but this is less efficient (two iterations over the elements and more memory usage) :

```
for (Object o : Collections.list(e))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you mean [IteratorIterable](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/IteratorIterable.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html) legacy class is analogous to the modern [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) class.  Both represent a current iteration over data.

The enhanced for loop was designed to work with [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) and arrays, but notably *not* with `Iterator`.  `Iterable` provides an [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()) method, which returns an `Iterator` over its data.

While it isn't possible to use the enhanced for loop with `Enumeration` or its modern `Iterator` equivalent, the [`forEachRemaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer)) method in `Iterator` (added in Java 8) provides similar functionality.  Combining with [`Enumeration.asIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html#asIterator()) (added in Java 9) allows iterating over an enumeration in a similar manner as the enhanced for loop:

```java
Enumeration<Object> e = ...
e.asIterator().forEachRemaining(o -> {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an Enumeration (and most classes derived from this interface) does not implement Iterable.

You can try to write your own wrapper class.

Comment: You shouldn't write a wrapper for Enumeration that turns it into an Iterable any more than you should create such a wrapper for Iterator. Iterator and Enumeration objects are stateful with respect to iteration. Iterables are not.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Surprisingly enough, while that appears to be the pattern (and a good pattern to continue to follow), there doesn't appear to be any documented restriction that an `Iterable` needs to be able to statelessly produce `Iterators`.