# Is there a one-liner to create a Collection from an Enumeration object?

Tags: java, collections

I have an Enumeration object and I want to create a Collection object containing the items of the enumeration.

Is there any Java function to do this without manually iterating over the enumeration? Something like the reverse of the `Collections.enumeration` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, there is [`Collections.list(enumeration)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list%28java.util.Enumeration%29)

(There is also [`EnumerationUtils.toList(enumeration)`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/EnumerationUtils.html#toList%28java.util.Enumeration%29) from [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).)

Answer (score 2):

<s>There's nothing in the standard API, because Enumerations and Iterators are not considered first-class API entities as in the C++ STL. You're supposed to consume them immediately after creation (ideally implicitly via the "enhanced for loop").</s>

[`Collections.list()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list%28java.util.Enumeration%29)

Comment: Enumerations cannot be used in the enhanced for loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240/why-arent-enumerations-iterable